# Identifying topics of blog posts by taxonomy / natural language / elasticsearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, taxonomy

I want to do some analysis on a set of blog posts, specifically to determine what topics the posts are about. We can assume the blog posts will be in English.

The data is stored in an elasticsearch system, so perhaps aggregations would be useful?

I am looking for guidance on how I could go about doing this. For instance, if I were to explore utilizing a taxonomy set, what would be a good way to do the mapping?

If taxonomies are the way to go, is there any good standard taxonomy to make use of or is it necessary to build out own?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ElasticSearch supports [Significant Topics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html) out of the box. This feature is experimental.

Comment: ok thanks, we'll take a look at that.